# Google map during setup coordinate is blinking

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have HTML page, which contain Google map. I have timer, which call function ,which move map. Map is moved but it is blinking every time. So how fix this bug?

```
function Replace(lt,ln)
{
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: location,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: { style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: { style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln);
    var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: companyPos,
        map: map,
        title: "Test"
    });

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, you create a new maps-instance each time you run this function(what results in the blinking).

Separate the code, create the maps/marker-instance on the first run, later only update map-center and marker-position :

```
function Replace(lt,ln){

    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln);
    var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, ln);
    //map not created yet
    if(!window.map){
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: location
          };
          //Note: map and companyMarker must be global
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
                                     myOptions);
          companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: companyPos,
            map: map,
            title: "Test"
          });
    }
    //map already initialized, update center and position
    else{
      map.setCenter(location);
      companyMarker.setPosition(companyPos);
    }
}
```